# Replace text in file with SED

Tags: git, sed

I am using git for a rails project and I have in an old committed file the following line: `user_name: 'ENV[GMAIL_SMTP_USER]',`

I'm trying to replace this line of all the old commits so I can take off the quotes(') and replace them inside the brackets: `user_name: ENV['GMAIL_SMTP_USER'],`. I am using `sed` and `--tree-filter` to accomplish it. Like the following:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "sed -i .bkp s/'ENV[GMAIL_SMTP_USER]'/ENV['GMAIL_SMTP_USER']/g config/environments/development.rb" -f
```

This command runs fine without errors, but it does not take out the quotes. Also, I can say that the command really works for replacing, since before that, I've successfully used to update `user_name: 'myGmailUserName'` to `user_name: 'ENV[GMAIL_SMTP_USER]'`

The problem is only with removing the quotes. What is missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you just need to remove the space between `-i` and `.bkp`.

Comment: Thanks for answering @ooga, but it didn't work. It runs without error, but do not accomplish the repositioning of the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cyrus suggested, I had a problem with escaping, but it was with the quote itself. And also, I don't know why, even with the escaping, it did not work with the repository I was working with, which was a cloned repository (backup).

So, I created a new clone repository and run the following escaping the quotes:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "sed -i.bkp s/\'ENV[GMAIL_SMTP_USER]\'/ENV[\'GMAIL_SMTP_USER\']/g config/environments/development.rb" -f
```

Does anybody has a better answer? Maybe explaining why it didn't work in the first clone repository...

Comment: You should edit your original post, not posting respond to your own post.

Comment: @Jotne, Stack Exchange actually encourages people to answer their own question. See for reference: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: It's OK to answer your own question, however it is not OK to ask more questions in your answer. You should edit in this instance.

Comment: @Andrew, the first time I answered there wasn't this question. However, while looking for the right etiquete, I've found a question about this here in Stack exchange where people seemed to understand that, in case you answer your own question, you should leave an other question giving the chance for other people to Answer better than you. That is why I've edited and placed the question. See reference:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Comment: Fair enough.  I think generally edits to the question are a better approach but that's just me.

Comment: Guys, thanks for questioning this methods, it made me search and learn about Stack Overflow best practices. I just want to do the right thing! 
Other indicators that I've found for answering your own question is that, in fact you have the button which allows you to do it. And even have a Badge (Self-Learner) for responding your own question and getting 3 upvotes.

Comment: You didn't take Cyrus' advice to escape the brackets.  You need to escape those too I think.

Comment: @Andrew I've verified my old commits with 'git show sha1:filename' and I've accomplished the quote replacing correctly. I am running on Mac OS X. Don't know if makes any difference from maybe linux. Anyways, I think it wouldn't be a problem to escape the brackets as well.

Answer (score 2):

Escape `[` and `]` with a `\` in search pattern:

```
echo "user_name: 'ENV[GMAIL_SMTP_USER]'," | sed "s/user_name: 'ENV\[GMAIL_SMTP_USER\]',/user_name: ENV['GMAIL_SMTP_USER'],/"
```

Output:

```
user_name: ENV['GMAIL_SMTP_USER'],
```

Comment: your command works  on the terminal, but when I put it inside the git filter-branch parameter I receive the following error: "s/": unterminated substitute pattern .  I've found the solution my self by escaping the quotes in identical repository. Lucky, I was working on a clone of the real repository. I had tried escaping quotes in the cloned repository but I don't know why it didn't work. With the a new cloned repository it worked... go figure... I'll post the answer and upvote you for pointing a possible escaping problem! Thanks man!